# How to send parameter from one file to another

Tags: java, class, mergesort

I created a merge-sort program in Java. I want to use that program in some other Java file by importing that file, but I don't know how to send my array from my initial class to the `MergeSort` class. I just started using java and haven't really tried this, so I need your help or any suggestions to do this.

Here's my `MergeSort` code

```java
public class MergeSort{
    public static void Merge(int[] array,int low,int mid,int high){
        int i = low;
        int j = mid+1;
        int k = low;
        int[] temp = new int[array.length];
        while(i<=mid&&j<=high){
            if(array[i]<array[j]){
               temp[k] = array[i];
               i++; 
            }
            else{
                temp[k] = array[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(i>mid){
            while(j<=high){
                temp[k]=array[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        else{
            while(i<=mid){
                temp[k]=array[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        for(k=low;k<=high;k++){
            array[k] = temp[k];
        }
    }
    public static void MergeSort(int[] array,int low,int high){
        if(low<high){
            int mid = (low+high)/2;
            MergeSort(array,low,mid);
            MergeSort(array,mid+1,high);
            Merge(array,low,mid,high);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {10,2,15,1,25,40};
        MergeSort(array,0,array.length-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this ?  "but i dont know how to send my array from my initial class to the mergeSort class" , you have no mergeSort class in your code also class should start with capital letter and function with no capital, however if you want "send" something to another class you must initialize that class first or if it is a static field in your new class you can set it directly by YourClass.staticFieldInYourClass= your value;

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {10,2,15,1,25,40};
        MergeSort.MergeSort(array,0,array.length-1);
    }
}
```

Method `MergeSort`, in class `MergeSort` is static and public. Hence you can call it from any method in any class. The import depends on the packages that the two classes are in. There is no `package` statement in the code in your question, hence I assume that class `MergeSort` is in the *default* package. Therefore, class `OtherClass` (in the code above) is also in the *default* package. When both classes are in the same package, you don't need to import anything.

> I just started using java

Then I recommend Oracle's [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

I also suggest that you adopt [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Thankyou , i will definitely improve my naming conventions ,  thats not what i asked but okay